# LaTeX moderncv casual: omit icons

Tags: moderncv

I am preparing my CV with moderncv and chose the casual style. Now, I would like to omit the icons for phone, email etc. How do I do this?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You just have the redefine the several symbols to be empty.  For example for the adress symbol you use:

```
\renewcommand*{\addresssymbol}{}
```

For all symbols (choose that one you need, comment the others)  see the following MWE (after personal datas you find the redefinition of the symbols):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}    

% character encoding
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
 \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.5cm}  

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                              
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             
\social[github]{jdoe}                              
\extrainfo{additional information}  
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}  
\quote{Some quote}                  

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}

\renewcommand*{\addresssymbol}{} % <=====================================
\renewcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\fixedphonesymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\faxphonesymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\homepagesymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\linkedinsocialsymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\twittersocialsymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\githubsocialsymbol}{} % <================================


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description} 
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\cvitem{Staatsangehörigkeit}{Deutsch}
\cventry{\textbf{Staats\-angehörigkeit}}{Deutsch}{}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: personal data only]

Comment: Note that in recent versions, the call is `\mobilesymbol`, not `\mobilephonesymbol`.